# Apex Triggers to solve my Opps and Contracts problem

Tags: apex, opportunity, contracts

Following from my previous question I'm still trying to link Opportunities and Cotnracts together and report on them.

Firstly, I now have a lookup relationship between Opportunities and Contracts so that my users can now create a contract straight from their opportunities.

I've gone down the road of creating a custom object to serve as a data junction. This object contains the Master-Detail fields Opportunity__c (and Opportunity Name lookup field) and Contract__c (a Contract Number lookup field).

I had the thought of creating some Apex triggers to populate these fields upon creation of an Opportunity and Contract. My first attempt, populating the Opportunity__c field with the Opportunity.Name field is thus:

```
trigger ApplyOppNameToJunction on Opportunity (before insert) {    
      Opportunities_and_Contracts__c bb = Opportunity__c;
      for (Opportunity aa : trigger.new){
          aa.Opportunity.Name = bb.Opportunity__c;
      }  
}
```

but this won't save. It tells me

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Opportunity_c at line 2
>   column 40

even though that field does exist within the Opportunities_and_Contracts__c object. As this is only stage one and I'm aleady htiting stumbling blocks, can anybody offer any advice?

I do have more queries too:

Once this si sorted, I can set something similar to populate the Contract__c field. My hope is that this would then happen:

User creates Opportunity - Opportunity name automaitcally populated in junction record.
User creates Contract from Opportunity - Contract number automatically populated into related junction record.

Can anyone point out if I need anything else to get this to work?

Comment: Your error suggests you have a typo in the code, although its not shown above.  Its saying that you have Opportunity_c (only 1 underscore), where it should be Opportunity__c (2 underscores)

Comment: I retyped the field name and got this instead

Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Opportunity__c at line 2 column 40

Comment: Can you go to the custom lookup field on the Opportunities_and_Contracts__c object and confirm the name of the lookup field is the default Opportunity__c, and you didnt name it something different.

Comment: Definitely called Opportunity__c

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `Opportunities_and_Contracts__c bb = Opportunity__c;`?

Comment: I'm trying to specify the field within the Opportunities_and_Contracts__c object.

Comment: What are you trying to set it to, you have it outside of the loop.

Comment: Can you just tell us (not in code) what you ant this trigger to accomplish.  Might help as I am unclear as to what the end result you are looking for.

Comment: I want this trigger to create an Opportunities and Contracts record and apply the Opportunity Name to the Opportunity field within the O+C object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line number in your error is line 2, which is the line shown below:

```
Opportunities_and_Contracts__c bb = Opportunity__c;
```

If you are trying to create a new `Opportunities_and_Contracts__c` record every time an `Opportunity` is created then the code below will work. **Note** that I have changed the trigger to `after insert` so that the Opportunity Id is set and available to use.

```
trigger ApplyOppNameToJunction on Opportunity (after insert) {    
      List<Opportunities_and_Contracts__c> ocs = new List<Opportunities_and_Contracts__c>();
      for (Opportunity aa : trigger.new){
          ocs.add(new Opportunities_and_Contracts__c(Opportunity__c = aa.Id));
      }
      insert ocs;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this may sound a bit simple but what is defined as a Known Record?

Comment: I think there may be an issue as the Opportunity and Contracts record does not exist at the point in time when an Opportunity is created.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new Opportunities_and_Contracts__c record for each Opportunity that is inserted?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking as well, but it's unclear what the objective here is.

Comment: Yes, along with apending the Opportunity name into the new record.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja do you want to answer this, as you were first to comment on this?

Comment: No worries @BarCotter, you can have it.  Just wanted to make sure it was clear what he was trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've modified my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Thanks @BarCotter. I applied to code and it save correctly. However, when I try to create an opportunity it produces an error. I'll post it in a separate comment so it makes sense. I've figured out it's because the other field in my custom object, Contract__c, is a mandatory field as it is another Master Detail relationship

Comment: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger ApplyOppNameToJunction caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ApplyOppNameToJunction: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Contract]: [Contract]: Trigger.ApplyOppNameToJunction: line 6, column 1

Comment: I changed the Contract__c field type to a LookUp and it allowed it. I'm going to work on the trigger to apply the contract details when a contract is created. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CaptainHaz, glad that you were able to get it working.  In addition to accepting Bar's answer, you should upvote it as well.  :)

Comment: All done, @sfdc_ninja. I'm still quite new to this. I do have another query which is related to this whole thing but is it worth going for another question as it's quite large?

Comment: Absolutely.  You would want to open a new question so that other people will have visibility to it.  when you ask larger follow up questions in comments, it tends to get lost and has very limited visibility for people who may have an answer and also for those with similar issues looking for an answer.  Ask a new question and we can jump over and try to help there.